# Swift Playground force next page

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm developing a Playground with many widgets and one of these is a button. The function of this button is force to change to the next page. Is it possible?

I only found the next markup comment for go to the next page and need to render the playground for do it. This isn't useful for my project.

```
//: [Next](@next)
```

Thanks in advance,

Best.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. The whole idea of a Playground (book) is to let the user turn the page for himself, it means you can't do it by code.

Also, it would be a bad practice. Each page should consist of a single experience with an explanation, maybe a goal to achieve, and then the user will turn the page whenever he wants.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way: `PlaygroundPage.current.navigateTo(page: .next)`

You also can use `.previous` and `.pageReference(reference: String)`

And here is how I use it:

```
//#-hidden-code
import PlaygroundSupport

if assessmentPassed {
    // Actually if you force navigate to the next page you don't really need assessment as it will not be shown
    PlaygroundPage.current.assessmentStatus = .pass(message: "Great! Let's go to the next page...")
    PlaygroundPage.current.navigateTo(page: .next)
} else {
    PlaygroundPage.current.assessmentStatus = .fail(hints: ["Here goes hint"], solution: "Here goes solution")
}
//#-end-hidden-code
```